# Prove that 2 sets have the same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to show that the cardinality of: $$ A \cdot B  $$ equal to the cadinality of $$ B \cdot A $$ In other words , I need to show that there is a bijection between them. How to aproach to this.. (A and B can be finite or infinte)
Thank you

Comment: Take $f: A.B \rightarrow B.A$ as $f(a.b)=b.a$

Comment: What is $A \cdot B$? Is it the cartesian product?

Comment: Is it standard to write $A \cdot B$ to mean cartesian product?

Comment: @Mankind: well, if the structure isn't commutative, it is wrong in general.

Comment: What is dot? If it's an algebraic operation that is not commutative, then the cardinalities might not be equal. If it's cartesian product, then... come on, it's trivial.

Comment: Now , after some of the answers , I understand that is trivial but I didn't saw it at the beginning. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Define $f:A\times B\to B\times A$, $f(a,b)=(b,a)$.

Obviously, $f$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

The result you are really getting at here is given two cardinal numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ show that $\alpha\beta = \beta\alpha$. That is cardinal multiplication is commutative. To this end, let $A$ and $B$ be sets with $|A| = \alpha$ and $|B| = \beta$. We must show that $|A \times B| = |B \times A|$. Now, let $f: A \times B \to B \times A$ be defined by $f((a,b)) = (b,a)$. This is clearly a bijection. Hence, $|A \times B| = |B \times A|$.